# How do you sum up integers on separate lines in vim?

Tags: arithmetic

I have a list of integers, where each is on a separate line. I'm trying to find a quick way to sum them up directly in VIM without having to write a script that does it for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What worked for me was:

```
:%!awk '{print; total+=$1}END{print total}'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this command:

```
com! -range=% Sum :echo eval(join(getline(<line1>,<line2>),'+'))
```

It basically gets the lines in the given range (by default whole file) as a list, and evaluates it by joining each list item with a `+` between each other.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fun (albeit slightly hacky) answer, although I believe it's the shortest answer you'll get:

```
:%norm Dj@"<C-v><C-a><cr>
p
```

(note that `<C-v>` means ctrl-v, and `<C-a>` means ctrl-a)

It works by doing the following on every line:

- Deleting it (into the unnamed register)
- Running the unnamed register as a count, and
- Incrementing the next number by that much.

Then, on the last line, there isn't a next number to increment, so it breaks. However, we have the current sum in the unnamed register, so we can just paste it with `p`.

If you don't want a  bunch of blank lines, you could modify the last line to `V{p`.

Unfortunately, this only works with positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

Use reduce function:

```
echo getline(1, '$')->reduce({acc, val -> acc + val})
```